# Login to a webpage in Java with Facebook Connect

Tags: java, facebook

I have a webpage that I can login to using facebook connect.  I need to grab the html from a page but it requires a login first.  Does anyone know a way to authenticate myself using my facebook credentials in Java so I can grab the pages I need?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are asking about is a standard rest authentication mechnism called O-AUTH.

Here is one decent library I use on occasion, this is specifically for facebook... I would read on how to do some of these o-auth things yourself. It seems scary but it isn't.

Its alot like rest... alot of idea, no real concrete standard.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

This will get you started, but after you have connected to facebook and twitter... id recommend either building your own, or finding a fluid o-auth library for all your social networks.

The graph tag api is easy, once you get auth down, the rest of facebook (though pretty challenging) comes with time.